# how to read value of style[“display”] property of webcontrol

Tags: c#, html, css

I have

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorFrom" runat="server" CssClass="ErrorLabel" ControlToValidate="FromDateTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:GlobalResources, StartDateRequired %>">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

and the css

```
.ErrorLabel
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

if my FromDateTextBox is empty I get the error message.

I want to check in my C# code whether my error is published on my page or not.

when I check the elementit from element inspection in chromewhen I don't have the error it's like this:

```
<span id="ctl00_PageMainContent_RequiredFieldValidatorFrom" class="ErrorLabel" style="color: red; display: none;">Start date required</span>
```

and when I have it it's like:

```
<span id="ctl00_PageMainContent_RequiredFieldValidatorFrom" class="ErrorLabel" style="color: red; display: inline;">Start date required</span>
```

just the display changes.
but how can I check this change in my c# code? I want to enable/disable a button based on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding validation group

1) Add validationgroup property to the controls like below in your .aspx page

```
 ValidationGroup="FormSubmit"
```

2) Use the below method to find whether that group is valid or not

```
protected bool IsGroupValid(String sValidationGroup)
{
    foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.Validators)
       {
          if (validator.ValidationGroup == sValidationGroup)
              {
                 bool fValid = validator.IsValid;
                 if (fValid)
                 {
                     validator.Validate();
                     fValid = validator.IsValid;
                     validator.IsValid = true;
                 }
                 if (!fValid)
                     return false;
              }
         }
         return true;
}
```

3) And finally call the above method in your code behind by passing the group name to check whether that group is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks it works but the problem is that if I remove the date from the FromDateTextBox it does not disactivate/activate the button untill I click one of comboxes(in fact untill I awake SelcetedIndexChanged event somewhere
can you help me how can I trigger the utton event then?

Comment: in that case you can check at the client side instead of server end in javascript like `if (Page_ClientValidate('Validation Group Name'))`